# Polymorphic path help. (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation in which I had to replicate a feature for another part of my app.  Because this is the same feature used in a twice, I knew that I would have to update the routes that are associated with it.  However the routes that I have are a little different because there are two ID's in the url.

Originally I had this for my routes

```
=link_to edit_admin_customer_content_setting_path(@owner, @owner)
```

The URL would have this:

```
admin/customer/1/content_settings/1/edit
```

Now the problem is I need to also use these with another feature, being 'prospects'.  With this in mind, the first thing I did was add my content_settings routes as a concern under my 'prospects' within my routes file.

However i eventually ran into a problem in my partial in that I had two routes that were dependent upon what part of my app the partial is used. I also can't just have these two buttons listed next to each other, that wouldn't work.

```
=link_to edit_admin_customer_content_setting_path(@owner, @owner)
=link_to edit_admin_prospect_content_setting_path(@owner, @owner)
```

So i've tried a polymetric path at

```
=link_to "Edit Content Settings", polymorphic_path([:edit, :admin, @owner, :content_setting, @owner])
enter code here
```

and I keep getting an error at

```
'edit_admin_customer_content_setting_customer_path'
```

I apologize if this has become a little winded. Is there anything that I might be missing to get this working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually figured out the solution.  The problem is that I have two id's in my routes, which caused me to used (@owner, @owner). But ultimately the second ID was never needed. Additionally this caused problems because polymorphic paths aren't really designed for having two ids.....actually routes in general aren't really designed to have two IDs.

The solution was to nix the second ID in the first place, and to do that I had to update my resource in my routes file. My resource was 'content_settings'. But it needed to be 'content_setting'.  By making it singular, the second id was removed, and it has allowed me to make a go through with my polymorphic adventure.